# Bootstrap Progress Bar disappears

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I am using Bootstrap progress bar:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:40%"></div>
</div>
```

Progress-Bar works fine, but after some time the progress-bar disapprears and [object Object] is visible in place of progress-bar. Emptying cache and deleting cookies of my browser fixes the issue.

Comment: use jsfiddle to show your problem..

Comment: @shri - Please see this [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rjain136/3fp36mj9/2/).

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: Why do you put your progress-bar on right? And why is it so short? Any reason?

Comment: @yuyokk - Chrome 42.0 +

Comment: @GreenFox - Its a project requirement. The progress-bar appears within a grid column's cells.

Comment: I hope you could draw a picture of the desired output so we can help you more. Kudos!